# C Class Instance from Void Pointer using Ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes, void-pointers

I've got a C DLL that exposes a handful of methods that return `void pointers` to a Class like so:

```
void *GetLicense() {
    static AppLicenseImpl ipds_;
    return (void *) &ipds_;
}
```

In C++, after loading the DLL, I'd do this to work with it:

```
typedef void *(* FPGetLicense)();
GetLicense_ = (FPGetLicense)GetAddress("GetLicense");
license_ = (AppLicense *) GetLicense_();
license_->GetApplicationStatus(); // Load data so that other calls don't fail
```

I can't figure out how to parallel that in Python.  This gets me the pointer:

```
d = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('license.dll')
d.GetLicense.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
p = d.GetLicense() # returns ptr loc, something like 8791433660848L
```

But I obviously can't call `p.GetApplicationStatus()` in Python.  Does anyone have a suggestion on how I'd instantiate that Class the rest of the way in Python so that I can call `GetApplicationStatus()`?

Comment: What do you mean by "instantiate that class the rest of the way"? The instance has already been fully instantiated when `GetLicense` returns—at least it had better be, or the next line of C++ is going to segfault.

Comment: My apologies, my terminology is probably bad.  Does that require that there be an analogous class definition in my Python module that reflects the `AppLicense` class in the c/c++ code?

Comment: Well, your C code can't possibly have any reference to the `AppLicense` class. On top of that, there is no real portable way to reference C++ types from a .DLL/.so in C++ in the first place; this is why you generally have `extern "C"` wrappers that take a struct or void* as the first argument in the first place. But if you want to access members of a struct or class from `ctypes`, then yes, you need to define a `ctypes.Struct`. If you don't want to do that, consider using `cffi` or building custom bindings (possibly with `Cython`) instead of using `ctypes`.

Comment: You can make `AppLicense` a subclass of `c_void_p`. Then the instance `self` is a pointer to the C++ object. Add methods that wrap the `extern "C"` stubs that call the C++ methods. Add a `_check_retval_` method to centralize error checking the class when it's used as a `restype`.

Comment: @eryksun - Any chance you can show me some sample code to that effect?  I can't seem to wrap my head around making use of the pointer to get to the method I want.  I don't see how having `self` on my class refer to the pointer helps me.

Comment: Export an `extern "C"` function such as `AppLicense_GetApplicationStatus` that takes an `AppLicense *` and calls the `GetApplicationStatus` method. The Python `AppLicense` class (a subclass of `c_void_p`) has a `GetApplicationStatus` method that calls `d.AppLicense_GetApplicationStatus(self)`. You'd set `d.GetLicense.restype = AppLicense`, etc. As abarnert mentioned, you may want to look into alternatives for wrapping C++ libraries such as Boost.Python or SWIG.

Comment: @eryksun - Any chance you can post that as an answer so I can accept it?  Exporting another function to pass the pointer back to worked like I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent more time with this - from c++ when I want to work with the class instance the void pointer refers to I do something like this:

```
class AppLicense {
public:
    AppLicense() {}
    virtual LicenseStatus GetApplicationStatus() = 0;
}
```

But I couldn't figure out how to do that in Python.  This does not work:

```
class AppLicense(object):
  def GetApplicationStatus(self):
    pass
```

So instead I exported another function in the dll like this:

```
extern "C" {
    int P_GetApplicationStatus(void *ptr) {
        try {
            AppLicenseImpl * ref = reinterpret_cast<AppLicenseImpl *>(ptr);
            return ref->GetApplicationStatus();
        } catch (...) {
            return 0; // License Error default.
        }
    }
}
```

Once I had that in place, using it from Python is accomplished like this:

```
d.GetLicense.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
p = d.GetLicense()

d.C_GetApplicationStatus.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
status = d.P_GetApplicationStatus(p)
```

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#type-conversions):

> Sometimes you have instances of incompatible types. In C, you can cast one type into another type. `ctypes` provides a [`cast()`](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.cast) function which can be used in the same way.

So, the Python equivalent of the C++ code is:

```
license = cast(d.GetLicense(), ctypes.POINTER(AppLicense))
license.GetApplicationStatus()
```

However, often this isn't necessary; you may be able to just do this:

```
d.GetLicense.restype = ctypes.POINTER(AppLicense)
```

This looks like "cheating", but it really isn't. You're just telling it to call the `POINTER(AppLicense)` constructor with the result. And since `POINTER(AppLicense)` is a ctypes data type, it will not have to first assume the result is a C `int`.

Comment: Thanks, I think.  I am probably missing some scaffolding code in my python module for the class.  I'll do some additional reading and maybe update the question when I'm closer / have better tracebacks or can more succinctly ask the question.